# Why some properties have isRequired set to true?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I've simple class for representing Model

```
public class Test{
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Code")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9A-Za-z ]+$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "GeneralShowModel_Code_Error")]
        [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "GeneralShowModel_Code_Length_Error")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Range(0, Int16.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "GeneralShowModel_MaxGuests_Error")]
        [DisplayName("Max guests")]
        public long MaxGuests { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Pre-registration is closed")]
        public bool IsPreRegistrationClosed { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("In test mode")]
        public bool InTestMode { get; set; }
}
```

I created simple custom html helpers for rendering label with class 'required' when property has Required attribute

```
public static class CustomHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString RequiredLabelFor<T, TU>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper,
Expression<Func<T, TU>> expression)
    {
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
        var isRequired = metaData.IsRequired;
        var htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var label = new TagBuilder("label");
        label.SetInnerText(metaData.DisplayName);

        label.Attributes.Add("for", helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName));
        if (isRequired)
        {
            label.Attributes.Add("class", "required");
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(label.ToString());
    }
}
```

I use this helper in this way

```
@Html.RequiredLabelFor(m => m.Code)
```

MaxGuests,IsPreRegistrationClosed etc. haven't Required attribute but metaData.IsRequired is true. How to resolve this obstacle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `MaxGuests` is a primitive type that does not allow a `null` value. Hence, it is required.

Try this:

```
public long? MaxGuests { get; set; }
```

See the `?` after `long`. That makes it nullable.

Comment: @Victor: Any luck trying this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. Can we do this without  changing to nullable type, that is only via checking existing [Required] attribute?

Comment: @Victor: Not that I am aware of.